# Hiding keyboard transition when performing segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently implementing the registration for my app and I have 3 ViewControllers with one text field. I want to hide any keyboard transition between those view controllers.

For example:
When I am at VC: A and I am performing a segue with an open keyboard to VC: B, then one of the new text fields will become the first responder, and a small keyboard transistion will be visible. (First, the keyboard closes, and then the keyboard opens for the new fields again).

So how can I globally keep the keyboard open for multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not the best approach , put you can add the second VC as a child like this

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dd") as! secViewController

    self.addChildViewController(vc)

     self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

    // illusion of push VC

    vc.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5 , animations: {

              vc.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width)

        }

     )

    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. Unfortunately, I need all VCs wrapped up in a navigationController

Comment: @dfi did you figure out how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For globally keep the keyboard open for multiple view controllers, you have to put the `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` in your ViewControllers.(Where you wan to show the keyboard when page loads). Make the `IBOutlet` for your every  textfield.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

After implementing this if you could not see any keyboard appears in your simulator then simply press -

1. `cmd + k`  or
2. `shift + cmd + k`

Do this only for simulator. Thank you.

Comment: This is how I currently do it. There is still a small keyboard transition (a blink) between the viewControllers.

Comment: you mean the black space when keyboard appears?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a custom UINavigationController with an invisible or hidden UITextField (just zero the frame and add it to the subview) that you set to becomeFirstResponder on load.

From there, set that as the firstResponder every time you transition views, and set the real textField on viewDidAppear.